# check a checkbox in jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have here a number of checkboxes. just like this:

```
<div id = 'fCheck'> 
  <input type="checkbox" id="mango" value="mango" /> <label>MANGO</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="santol" value="santol" /> <label>SANTOL</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="guava" value="guava" /> <label>GUAVA</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="lomboy" value="lomboy" /> <label>LOMBOY</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="apple" value="apple" /> <label>APPLE</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="orange" value="orange" /> <label>ORANGE</label><br>
</div>
```

and I also have this data:

```
SupplierID     fruit_name       Granted
   10792        "mango"           "Y"
   10792        "santol"          "Y"
   10792        "guava"           "N"
   10792        "lomboy"          "N"
   10792        "apple"           "Y"
   10792        "orange"          "Y"
```

Now, what Im trying to do is that everytime I input that supplierID `10792` (through ajax call), all the fruits that has a `Y` in granted field, will be shown in the through the checkbox above, while the `N` will left unchecked. Can please help me out?
Checking the checkboxes based on `granted yes or no` is problem. thanks

**My ajax call:**

```
var params = {
  "SessionID": $.cookie("SessionID"),
  "dataType":"data"
};
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'processjson.php?' + $.param({path:'supplier/view',json:JSON.stringify(params)}),
  dataType: primeSettings.ajaxDataType,
  success: function(data) {
    if ('error' in data)
    {
      showMessage('ERROR: ' + data["error"]["msg"]);
    }
    else{ 
      $.each(data['result']['main']['rowdata'], function(rowIndex, rowDataValue) {
      var groupFlag=0;
        $.each(rowDataValue, function(columnIndex, rowArrayValue) {
          var fldName = data['result']['main']['metadata']['fields'][columnIndex].name;
          if (fldName == 'supplier_id'){
            supplierID = rowArrayValue; //alert(rightCode);
            if (supplierID == SupID){//check if the supplier found
              groupFlag=1;
            }
          }
          if (fldName == 'fruit_name'){
            fruitname = rowArrayValue;
          }
          if (fldName == 'granted'){
            grant = rowArrayValue;
            if (groupFlag ==1){
              if (hasRight == 'y')
              $('#dialogUserGroupEdit').append('<input type="checkbox" id="'+ rightGroupCode +'" value="'+ rightDesc +'" /> <label>'+rightDesc+'</label><br>');
              //must check the checkbox here that have the same fruit_name in the html

            }
          }
        });
      });
    }
  }      
})
```

Comment: huh? where is this table? how are you getting the information. etc...

Comment: What's your ajax returning? A JSON object?

Comment: @ReX, yes, its json object. But my check box is only html.

Comment: how is your <del>table</del> data returned? can you post a raw output of your XHR response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out now. Here's what happen. Everytime I input the '**supplier ID**', it will call my ajax and check my supplier table (only under that ID) if the fruits is granted or not. If i see a fruit that is **granted**, it will loop all the checkboxes I have and check the **fruitsID** if it exist. If found, then check box will be check.

here's my answer that greatly work for me:

```
               $("input:checkbox").each(function(){
                  if ($(this).attr("id") ==  fruitName){
                     $(this).attr("checked",true);
                  }                                     
               });
```

And here is my complete ajax call.

```
var params = {
  "SessionID": $.cookie("SessionID"),
  "dataType":"data"
};
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'processjson.php?' + $.param({path:'supplier/view',json:JSON.stringify(params)}),
  dataType: primeSettings.ajaxDataType,
  success: function(data) {
    if ('error' in data)
    {
      showMessage('ERROR: ' + data["error"]["msg"]);
    }
    else{ 
      $.each(data['result']['main']['rowdata'], function(rowIndex, rowDataValue) {
      var groupFlag=0;
        $.each(rowDataValue, function(columnIndex, rowArrayValue) {
          var fldName = data['result']['main']['metadata']['fields'][columnIndex].name;
          if (fldName == 'supplier_id'){
            supplierID = rowArrayValue; //alert(rightCode);
            if (supplierID == SupID){//check if the supplier found
              groupFlag=1;
            }
          }
          if (fldName == 'fruit_name'){
            fruitname = rowArrayValue;
          }
          if (fldName == 'granted'){
            grant = rowArrayValue;
            if ((groupFlag ==1) && (granted == 'Y')){
               $("input:checkbox").each(function(){
                  if ($(this).attr("id") ==  fruitName){
                     $(this).attr("checked",true);
                  }                                     
               });
            }

          }
        });
      });
    }
  }      
})
```

Answer (score 0):

While creating the markup for these checkboxes you can add a selected="selected attribute in the input tag for those items where Granted == "Y". You dont have to do this through jquery on page load.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF Granted="Y"
<input checked="checked" />
```

just add **checked="checked"** wherever you want the checkbox to be checked by default.

Comment: I hope its easy as that. But I have to look back again in my html and check the ID that have the same as my table...I dont know to code that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this (not tested) -

```
   $.each(results, function() {
       if (this.Granted === 'Y') $('input:checkbox[id=' + this.fruit_name  + ']').attr('checked',true);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to scan your table and check the box for each found row.

```
$('#table tr').each(function() {
   var name = $(this).find('td.eq(2)').text();
   var granted = $(this).find('td.eq(3)').text();

   var chk = $('#fCheck #'+name); //$('#fCheck input[value="'+name+'"]');

   if (granded.toLowerCase() == 'y') {
      chk.attr('checked', true);
   } else {
      chk.removeAttr('checked');
   }
});
```

Note that this selects **every** row of the table, you will need to narrow this to the rows only containing your supplier id in the first column if the table contains more rows.

Comment: my table is not displayed. I just have to put an ID in a text box and call an ajax. Then look for the fruits that have a `y`. if found, then check the checkbox in my html. My table is not shown here

Comment: then you should have mentionned "data" instead of "table"